# 7 Wonders Duel Pantheon: Anubis

Tags: expansions, 7-wonders-duel, pantheon

In 7 Wonders Duel Pantheon, the Anubis Divinity card is defined in the rulebook as follows:

> Anubis: Discard a card previously used to construct a Wonder (an opposing one or one of your own). The affected player doesn't lose the instant effects previously granted by that Wonder (Coins, Progress tokens, constructed or discarded cards, Replay effect). It is possible to *rebuild* this Wonder and thus apply its effects once again.

Does this effectively mean that the Wonder is *deconstructed*? The fact that you can rebuild it, seems to imply this. So does this then mean that you also lose the Production of the Wonder (for Piraeus and The Great Lighthouse), as well as the victory points that the Wonder might be worth at end of the game?

Would it be more clear to state:

> Anubis: Deconstruct any previously built Wonder (an opposing one or one of your own) and discard the card used to construct it. The affected player doesn't lose any instant effects previously granted by that Wonder (Coins, Progress tokens, constructed or discarded cards, Replay effect). It is possible to rebuild this Wonder and thus apply its effects once again.

Comment: Is this helping a bit to clarify? https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1661638/question-about-anubi

Comment: @Zibelas Yes it does. Unfortunately, Anubis is misspelled in the title of that question and I did not encounter it during a first search. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discussion about it at [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1661638/question-about-anubi) about the various interactions with anubis and wonders. The key points are

- All wonders: no VP if it remained unbuilt at end of age 3
- Sanctuary: stops providing discount until rebuilt
- Great Lighthouse: stops providing stone/clay/wood until rebuilt
- Piraeus: stops providing glass/paper until rebuilt

And when you get the instant effect of the wonder again when building it again (Coins, Progress tokens, constructed or discarded cards, Replay effect)

It is a tactical decision if you use it on your own wonder or the opponents. Good reasons to use it on not your own wonder are

- it is a wonder without instant effects (Great Lighthouse or Pyramids) and/or
- the opponent needs to pay many coins to rebuild it (because he lacks expensive resources for it) and/or
- the opponent used a card to build the wonder which you particularly want (which should often be the case) and you still have access to the discard pile (with the Mausoleum or Hades).